# How to install ROR to ubuntu 12.04 ? Getting error with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04, sqlite3-ruby

I'm new in ROR. So when I'm trying to install ROR.
    when I try to start rails(`rails s`) I get such error:

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

P.S. I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

and

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

and then Run

```
bundle install
```

you just read error messages instruct you to.

```
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 0):

The blog of RyanBigg is perfect to install ROR for ubuntu. So following link may help you.
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/